# Infrared Receiver

Tags: infrared

I am Designing a project to use An IR remote and i am confused about the receiver. I noticed some have two legs such as [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/171764666221?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

And others have 3 legs as seen in this [one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266)

Can someone tell me the difference?

Comment: Have you tried to read a description?

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ir-communication

Answer (score 2):

The Ebay one is an [IR Photodiode, a diode that is sensitive to IR input.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode)

> A photodiode is a semiconductor device that converts light into current. The current is generated when photons are absorbed in the photodiode.

The Sparkfun one is an IR Receiver, for Modulated IR. It takes a modulated IR signal, and strips the modulation, passing any digital signal inside to another IC. Typically used in Remote Control setups. [The wiki page for the RC-5 Remote Control protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC-5) provides a good explanation of how an IR Receiver works.

An Photodiode is a dumb analog part. A IR Receiver is a digital part (though it may have analog circuits inside).

For a remote code receiver, you need a IR Receiver. It requires a modulated signal in order to tell the difference between an intentional signal like a remote, and noise from lights in the room.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'this' and 'one' link are both to standard 3-legged IR receiver modules, the ebay link is (most probably, you never know on ebay) an IR LED (tranmitter).

==================================

Now that you edited the question: your 'one' is a standard 3-leg receiver, 'this' is most likely an IR emitter LED (but it could be an IR receiver diode, which is not what you want to receive a remote control signal).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at datasheet for those with three legs you will notice at the input a photodiode, well that's exatly the one with two legs.